# Create an open listener for info from website Java?

Tags: java, web, listener

I've looked everywhere and was unable to find any information on how to create a java listener that listens for information from a website and then reads the information.

I basically want the listener to be running in the background all the time.

It woudl be a website I control, I would have the website send data when a user checks out and I want to know how to listen for that data in the background without it being in intervals.

Comment: You need listner which triggers when new information updated in another website is it ?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to implement a [listener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for a website, because websites do not publish updates that listeners can listen for.  The HTTP protocol has no notion of polling, notifications, or publish-subscribe. This is why search engines have to [crawl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) the internet.

What you can do is write a web crawler that polls the site(s) you're interested in every so often, and when the site updates have the crawler notify your listeners.

Going into how to design a good crawler is beyond what I can cover in this answer, but Programmers SE has a couple of relevant questions:

- [Roll your own web crawler to crawl one specific website that has multiple entries](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/97766/88040)
- [How to be a good citizen when crawling web sites?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/91760/88040)

Comment: What I want is sort of like a checkout listener, when someone checks out, it sends the data to me. Is this possible?

Comment: @Trevor Are you trying to add this listener to a site you control?  If so, just modify the checkout code to send the data you need.  If you're trying to listen to when someone interacts with a third party website, that isn't possible.  It would help if you added more detail and context to your question.  As is, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I edited it to add more detail explaining my situation.